# LaTeX table not working

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table using LaTeX, but it is not working properly.
Some problems are: It is overflowing on the next page, the text is scattered and the alignment is bad. I also want to add more text in the column name `idea`.

Please find the code given below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.4cm}||p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}| p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}

 \hline

 \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Data Structures}} \\

 \hline

 \textbf{No} & \textbf{Sigma name and all}  & \textbf{Idea}& \textbf{Construct Time(Runtime Time)} & \textbf{Construct Time (Space)} & \textbf{Searching data (Query)} & \textbf{Search head (Space)}\\
 \hline

 1  & ABCD    &  These algorithms achieve performance better than the classic &   O(NLkt) & O(nL)&O(L(kt + dnp)&O(1)\\ \hline

 2&   FGH  & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces & $O(dn \log n)$ & $O(dn)$ &222& $O(1)$\\ \hline

 3&LMPQ & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces &  008 & 666 & 242&333\\ \hline

 4    & RSTV & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces &  012 & 888 & 333&55\\ \hline

 5&   ZMNQ & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces &016 & 888 & 444&343\\ \hline

 6& WORP  & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces and MBR   &020 &555 & 444&333\\ \hline

 7& MNPO  & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces. Search based on data pruning and the radius of nodes.&024 & 888 &224&342\\ \hline
 \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not everything that fits in software tables (like excel, where sliders etc. are) will fit on the paper.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options (your question is duplicate to it). You should tell us, if you can change page layout, can table be rotated to `landscape` , minimal allowed font size, can column headers be shortened,  etc.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution:

- wider `\textwidth` determined by use of the `geometry` package
- `footnotesize` font size
- different widths of columns
- use of the `tabularray` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {c X[0.5, c] X[2.2, j] *{4}{X[0.7, c]}},
             colsep = 3pt,
             row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries, c, m}
             } 
\SetCell[c=7]{c}    Data Structures
        &       &       &       &       &       &                       \\
No      & Sigma name and all
                & Idea  & Construct Time (Runtime Time)
                                & Construct Time (Space)
                                        & Searching data (Query)
                                                & Search head (Space)   \\
 1  & ABCD      &  These algorithms achieve performance better than the classic 
                        & O(NLkt) 
                                & O(nL) & O(L(kt + dnp)
                                                & O(1)                   \\ 
 2  & FGH       & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces 
                        & $O(dn \log n)$
                                & $O(dn)$
                                        & 222   & $O(1)$                \\

 3  & LMPQ      & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces
                        & 008   & 666   & 242   & 333                   \\  
 4    & RSTV    & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces 
                        &  012  & 888   & 333   & 55                    \\ 
 5      & ZMNQ  & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces 
                        & 016   & 888   & 444   & 343                   \\
 6      & WORP  & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces and MBR   
                        & 020   & 555   & 444   & 333                   \\ 
 7      & MNPO  & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces. Search based on data pruning and the radius of nodes.
                        & 024   & 888   & 224   & 342                   \\
 \end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(grey lines are page borders)

**Addendum:**
Yes, this table can be set on classical way, which can be compiled also on Overleaf. Code as well result are lef elegant, but solution works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize%
                       \Centering}X}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize%
                       \RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c | C{0.7} | L{2.5} | *{4}{C{0.7}|} }
%
    \hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Data Structures}}                                   \\
    \hline
\textbf{No} 
    & \textbf{Sigma name and all}
                & \centering\textbf{Idea}  
                        & \textbf{Construct Time (Runtime Time)}
                                & \textbf{Construct Time (Space)}
                                        & \textbf{Searching data (Query)}
                                                & \textbf{Search head (Space)}   
                                                                        \\
    \hline
 1  & ABCD      &  These algorithms achieve performance better than the classic
                        & O(NLkt)
                                & O(nL) & O(L(kt + dnp)
                                                & O(1)                   \\
    \hline
 2  & FGH       & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces
                        & $O(dn \log n)$
                                & $O(dn)$
                                        & 222   & $O(1)$                \\
    \hline
 3  & LMPQ      & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces
                        & 008   & 666   & 242   & 333                   \\
    \hline
 4    & RSTV    & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces
                        &  012  & 888   & 333   & 55                    \\
    \hline
 5      & ZMNQ  & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces
                        & 016   & 888   & 444   & 343                   \\
    \hline
 6      & WORP  & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces and MBR
                        & 020   & 555   & 444   & 333                   \\
    \hline
 7      & MNPO  & is an algorithm for solving the approximate or exact Near Neighbor Search in high dimensional spaces. Search based on data pruning and the radius of nodes.
                        & 024   & 888   & 224   & 342                   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Zarko! The content in the idea column is covered by black strip. How to remove it?

Comment: @Shi, in my answer hasn't black strip ;-). How you compile my MWE? Do you use Overleaf? Overleaf has installed (to) old `tabularray` version which may make troubles.

Comment: @Shi do you mean a black strip to the right of that column? Might be an overfull-rule, do you compile using the `draft` option, or with `\overfullrule` > 0pt?

Comment: I am using overleaf

Comment: @Skillmon Yes black strip

Comment: Is it possible to modify above code so that it works in overleaf

Comment: @Shi, I'm afraid that no. As I'm informed, they will upgrade their installation sometime around October and than it will works as it. However, ask their support, if you can locally add last version of `tabularray` package. (I'm not use Overleaf). Another option is, that you locally install MiKTeX or Texlive and become independent from Overleaf.

Comment: @Shi, see Addendum to answer.